# Slow Internet over Ethernet (16.04.3 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet

I’ve seen this problem all over the internet, tried just about everything, but can’t find any solutions. I’m hooked in to my network via Ethernet using nVidia’s nForce MCP61 chip. It’s running the forcedeth driver at full-duplex 100 link speed. On my regular windows machine, I can get around 500Mbit/s download and around 20Mbit/s upload. But on this machine on the same network, I can only reach 0.4Mbit’s download and 0.2Mbit/s upload, tested on Speedtest.net. It’s odd and I’m looking for some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: it may have nothing to do with Ubuntu; but a networking issue. If you're on a school/work/shared network and use Ubuntu for other things you don't do with windoze; you may have tripped network policies that don't stop your connection, just throttle it. these rules are common at workplaces, schools etc.   if this is likely I'd suggest spoofing your network.id's (mac etc) & seeing if that helps etc.  if it's not that, I'd wireshark a windoze simple connection vs. your ubuntu to look & see what is different (shared lan looking for something to increase speed).  i don't know your hardware.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the response. I forgot to include, this is on my home network where I have full control. Would you still recommend wiresharking?

Comment: nah.  my wiresharking comment was to see if some 'work-driver' sent a packet that 'speed' up the shared network; if there was a policy such as that being home, you should know about it.   though I'd still check the settings (`route` for ubuntu, `route print` for windoze; `ifconfig/ipconfig`... etc inc. DNS for any clues... but if you set it up - sounds hardware related (to me) where I I don't know your hardware sorry.

Comment: @guiverc https://pastebin.com/raw/4iu9A8XP

Comment: try `sudo ifconfig enp0s7 down; sleep 3; sudo ifconfig enp0s7 up; sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1` and see if it makes any difference.  the down-up was just to delete your routing info (i didn't like the 192.168.0.0 & chAdmin in your routing table) & then point it to gw used by windoze.  (this won't save anything.. it's a dumb try.  if you're not on your box, use another nic - eg. i tested this on eth1 b/c I was using eth0 to connect [ssh] to my test box)   [you use IPv6 where I'm old & still use IPv4 as seen by my 'route'  (not `ip route`)]

Comment: @guiverc No luck. Also, just noticed that my outside ping to Speedtest.net is up at 50ms. My windows usually goes about 10-20. On my local network on the Ubuntu machine, it’s acting normal around 1ms, but outside network is slow.

Comment: @guiverc I downloaded a quick speed test server (https://github.com/adolfintel/speedtest) to the Ubuntu machine and ran the test on the windows machine. 1ms ping, 100 down and 100 up. Odd.

Comment: tell me what's in nm for DNS (network manage: connection-info), esp. if it differs to your windoze client. ie. is DNS slowing your system down??

Comment: My Windows is on Google’s Public DNS and Ubuntu was set to my router’s IP. After discovery of that, I set Ubuntu over to Google’s Public DNS also and the speed changed to 8 down and 3 up. An improvement, but not where it should be